# Prawn pdf Rotate image inside Table Cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, prawn

How to rotate an image inside a table cell with prawn.

```
images.each_with_index do |image,index|
      my_image = {:image => open("#{image.authenticated_url}"), image_width: 220}
        row += [my_image]
        table([row], :cell_style => {:border_width => 0, :rotate => 90, :rotate_around => :center})
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please tell us what happens or what error messages you get from the code you pasted.

Comment: hi Daiku
it just doesn't work simply no rotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that when i take a picture with ipad/iphone, prawn doesn't auto-rotate the image depending on the exif data.
I was trying to rotate the image in prawn,it didn't work, but now i am just  removing these exif data before uploading the image to S3 (aws server)

```
...
has_attached_file :image,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :styles => { :original => ''},
...
```

this last line just override the :original style with another one without it s exif data